# RO Valkyrie on Genymotion virtual device always says it has stopped

Tags: virtualbox, genymotion

I use samsung galaxy s4 4.4.4 virtual device on Genymotion. Already have gapps and updated it. Clash of Clans works fine but RO Valykyrie always says it has stopped. Someone knows how to fix it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try reinstalling first of all. And perhaps try launching from Play Store

Comment: Can you provide a playstore link to the app in your question?